# Simplest way to write excel files with python

Tags: python, excel, file

I just want to write time and name of recognized person from my live feed, and new file should be made for every day. I figured out the recognizing part but writing data to excel files is a bit difficult for me.
Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Product List.xlsx') #place "r" before the path string to address special character, such as '\'. Don't forget to put the file name at the end of the path + '.xlsx'
print (df)
```

Comment: Have you tried using this? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

I find openpyxl good for for writing to excel files. It's good if you want to keep the formatting of the original excel sheet too.

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook(r"C:\temp\temp.xlsx")
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

sheet['A1'] = "123"
sheet['A2'] = "abc"

wb.save(r"C:\temp\temp_x.xlsx")
```